# R clustering using 'within-groups linkage'

Tags: r, spss, hierarchical-clustering

I'm re-running a hierarchical analysis on a SPSS .sav file for the efficiency of R. The dataset looks like this:

```
id  hour0 hour1 hour2 ... hour23
1   0.5   0.3   0.1       1.1  
2   0.3   0.3   0.2       0.6
3   1.0   0.8   0.5       0.9
```

In SPSS I have to tell the software which variable is the case identifier ('id' here) so it would exclude it when creating the matrix. But I found no argument about it in R:

```
d <- dist(mydata, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
```

And also, there's no method option as 'squared euclidean distance' (which is used often in SPSS):

> method: the distance measure to be used. This must be one of "euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary" or "minkowski". Any unambiguous substring can be given.

Of course I can make the matrix by importing a dataset like this:

```
hour0 hour1 hour2 ... hour23  
0.5   0.3   0.1       1.1 
0.3   0.3   0.2       0.6 
1.0   0.8   0.5       0.9
```

But I want to keep the id here because I have to know which cluster every individual belongs to in the final output, like the SPSS hierarchical clustering output (clus# means SPSS provides a solution with # clusters):

```
id  hour0 hour1 hour2 ... hour23 clus7 clus6
1   0.5   0.3   0.1       1.1    3     3
2   0.3   0.3   0.2       0.6    7     6
3   1.0   0.8   0.5       0.9    1     1
```

And the last problem is that there's no argument as 'within-groups linkage' in R hierarchical clustering:

```
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")
```

> method: the agglomeration method to be used. This should be (an unambiguous abbreviation of) one of "ward", "single", "complete", "average", "mcquitty", "median" or "centroid".

In SPSS the 'average' method is divided into two methods: 'between-groups linkage' and 'within-group linkage' and the output might be different for the choice made between these two.

So does anyone know what I should do or what package I should install? The questions are:

1. squared euclidean distance method in matrix creating
2. case identifier
3. clustering belonging in the output
4. within-groups linkage method in the hierarchical clustering

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help... but I am not sure since i never worked with SPSS...

```
# 1)
# for square use
# according to:
```

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/squared-euclidean-distance-td883513.html

```
d <- d^2

# 2)
# take id´s as rownames
rownames(mydata) <- mydata[,1]
mydata <- mydata[, -1]
d <- dist(mydata, method = "euclidean")

fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")
plot(fit) # to see the tree

# 3)
max_k <- 5 # max members you want
cutree(fit, k=1:max_k)

# or for a fixed number eg. 5, get number
# of members per cluster
table(cutree(fit, k=5))

# ... and comparing two diffrent k values
table(cutree(fit, k=5), cutree(fit, k=8))


# 4)
# again I assume k=5
install.packages("fpc") # if not installed
require("fpc")
cluster.stats(d, cutree(fit, k=5))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first two solutions are quite a walk-around and I like it! Still reading the 'fpc' manual...within-groups linkage not found yet